# JMS ConnectionFactory NullPointerException

Tags: java, glassfish, jms, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to run a tutorial with JMS and I have a problem. I'm using the latest Glassfish version with the latest JavaEE SDK. I'm creating a `ConnectionFactory` resource in the Glassfish admin console and then trying to instantiate it in the code using the following call:

```
@Resource(mappedName = "jms/ExampleConnectionFactory")
private static ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
```

But I'm getting the `NullPointerException` on the following line:

```
Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you using the resource? If you are in a session bean, a message-driven bean, or a web component, do not declare the resource static: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncgl.html#bncgm

Comment: @perissf, I've removed the static classifier and this didn't resolve the issue, connectionFactory is still null.

Comment: It should work. Are you sure you are using the correct imports? Can you post more infos / details on how you setup the ConnectioFactory in GlassFish?

Comment: How are you getting references to instances of the class that has this declaration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having this problem as well while attempting to have a RESTful web service place a message onto a JMS queue.

For me, I followed this tutorial here (http://www.tricoder.net/blog/?p=128), and I needed to place an `@Stateless` annotation above my `public class...` code.

For some reason (I don't know why, as I am totally new to this) the `@Stateless` is required for dependency injection to work. (It says that in the source above)

EDIT: Even with that, while developing my app, I would sometimes have the `NullPointerException`.  Restarting Glassfish fixes the problem when that happens.

Answer (score 0):

JMS Consumer,

Try puting the `@Stateless` annotation to your class and add `javax.ejb.Stateless` package library.

I hope you find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2 things:

1. Specify the Properties for InitialContext:

   Properties props = new Properties();
                       props.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
                       Context initialContext = new InitialContext(props);
2. Add the library to your project (adjust path):

`C:\installs\glassfish\glassfish-4.1\glassfish\lib\gf-client.jar`